# emulating usb device with another PC

Tags: usb

Task:  Testing production software on PC notebook without production unit attached via USB and without changing prodcution software.

Goal:  Emulate production device with another PC.  The test application runs on the second PC to emulate our device commands/responses.

Challenge:  Using a USB bridge cable or other device requires that we can change the PID/VID to look like our device.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You [need](http://www.analog.com/en/evaluation/usb-emulatorbf/eb.html) a [hardware](http://www.kanecomputing.co.uk/emulators_usb.htm) [device](http://www.ti.com/devnet/docs/catalog/embeddedsoftwarefulldetails.tsp?actionPerformed=productFolder&productId=9976) on the second PC to do this type of emulation.

Comment: Yes, I need a USB Bridge.  The issue is can I make the USB Bridge have our the VID/PID device.  And, a development board will not work.  We process a huge amount a data.  I would like to store sample images on the emulator PC and send them as if they were acquired real time.  A dev board would not have the file storage I would need.

Comment: Check out the first link. They have devices that allow storage on the PC. @Audrius idea of using a android board would work well as you can write directly to the port.

Comment: Many development boards also have USB host ports where in these days external USB stick (tested) or maybe even SSD can be connected offering plenty of capacity.

Answer (score 0):

USB ports on a normal PC are USB host ports. Two such ports cannot be connected with each other directly. USB device (or USB OTG - switchable) ports can be found on programmable smartphones ([Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html), maybe others) and some developer boards like [these](http://www.calao-systems.com/articles.php?lng=en&pg=5940). I think you probably need to use a smartphone or developer board rather than ordinary PC as the your USB device emulator.